# Why are my support members alpacas and what do they do?

Tags: love-live-school-idol-festival

I'm getting Alpacas as support members from daily login bonuses - but the problem is that I can't find any way to use them. They don't show up in my member tab, I can't put them on a team and I can't use them to idolize my other members.

What are all of these alpacas good for and how do I use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special support members like Alpacas, Family members, and Teachers are used in practice to greatly increase EXP and/or Skill Exp or to sell for a bit extra G than you would get for selling normal members.

You can see the tab to select special members when you are in the Practice Screen.

You can read about each special support member on the Wiki [here](http://llsif.wikia.com/wiki/Support_Members), but as a rule of thumb, keep them around for Idols you want to quickly boost up, or if you are strapped for G they can quickly alleviate that.